# Отсортировать по отдельному полю

Tags: javascript, сортировка

У меня есть массив объектов`let arr = []`, в нем находятся такие объекты:

```js
class Obj
{
  constructor()
  {
    this.number = 0;
    this.value = "Value";
  }
}
```

У каждого объекта есть поле number, и нужно отстортировать по нему, можно ли тут как-то с методом sort либо еще как-то?

В коментариях сообщили что можно так: `arr.sort((a,b) => a.value-b.value)`, но я пробовал вот так: `objs = objs.sort((a,b) a.number-b.number)` но массив остается не отсортированный

Comment: @РустамГимранов index 0 в начале, наибольший в конце

Comment: `arr.sort((a,b) => a.value-b.value)` неужели сложно подобное написать самостоятельно?

Comment: @teran оно же не сортирует

Comment: а что же оно делает по вашему (`number` там конечно,а не `value`)? зы: `sort` возвращает отсортированный массив, а не меняет текущий.

Comment: @РустамГимранов я их меняю в коде сам.

Comment: @teran ну у меня objs = objs.sort((a,b) a.number-b.number) но массив остаеться с такими же элементами

Comment: @k0vpack обновите вопрос, как вы попробовали?

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц обновил

Comment: если вы именно так `(a,b) a.number-b.number` пробовали, то у вас там в консоли приведены ошибки синтаксиса должны быть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class Obj
{
  //let number;
  //let value;
  constructor(n,v)
  {
    this.number = n;
    this.value = v;
  }
}

let objects= [];
objects.push(new Obj(2,"2"));
objects.push(new Obj(3,"3"));
objects.push(new Obj(1,"1"));
objects.push(new Obj(4,"4"));

let objs = objects.sort((a,b) => a.number-b.number);

console.log(objs);
```